# How to upload large Javascript file from FileReader

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, filereader

I've made a web app that makes use of PDF.js to display PDF files (opened from local disk using HTML5 FileReader):

```
var fileReader;
fileInput.addEventListener("change", function(e){
  var files = e.target.files;
  if (!files || files.length === 0) return;
  var file = files[0];

  // Read the local file into a Uint8Array.
  fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = function(e){
    var uint8Array = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);

    // Use uint8Array to open PDF in PDF.js
  };
  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
});
```

On the request of the user, I want to transfer the loaded file to the server to modify the PDF:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/uploadPdf");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if (xhr.readyState === 4){
    if (xhr.status === 200){
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
    else {
      console.log(xhr);
    }
  }
};
xhr.send(fileReader.result);
```

This works just fine, until I try using a big PDF (65 MB in Chrome) - the browser just freezes for ~30 seconds while uploading the file.

Any suggestions to alternative approaches that will not freeze the browser, nor require the user to select the file again and preferably with a progress function?